# Appending a param value to a url while making network request in android using okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

**What I was doing:**
I was using android http library to make http requests

**What i am doing:** 
I have migrated into Oktttp now and i am using below code

---

***In doInBackground of an AsyncTask i am calling the below function***

```
public static String getRequestNoPayload(String urlString) throws Exception {

        client.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
        client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(urlString)
        .addHeader("phonenumber",AppController.getPhoneNumber())
        .addHeader("authtoken",AppController.getAuthCode())
        .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

**value of url:**

```
String urlString=Keys.login_api+"?phonenumber="+edtPhnoId.getText().toString().trim();
```

**What is happening:**

- Not able to send requests like this since i am appending the url with
  a param ?
- How to resolve this ... should i go for any specific encoding
  methods, if so which is that one
- Any sample would help

Comment: [Follow this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795931/android-okhttp-adding-params/38990465#38990465).It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()  
  .add("search", "Jurassic Park")
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()  
  .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
  .post(formBody)
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

https://publicobject.com/2014/06/12/okhttp-ate-mimecraft/